# Distribution over parameters vs. distribution over functions

Tags: distributions, gaussian-process, variational-inference

I find it hard to distinguish between these two concepts. In a variational inference setting we learn a distribution over the parameters of our function. in the definition of Gaussian processes we learn a distribution over functions. I wonder, when we have a distribution over the parameters of a function, then we have different functions, right? then I am unable to go further and tell the definition of Gaussian processes from the definition of a the posterior of a Variational inference apart. Would you please help me to clarify these two?